# How many instances of one class is there on server?

Tags: php

Is it possible to know how many instanced objects of one PHP class there is **on whole server** (for all users, not just for one thread).

Here is reason why I want to do it. I am making a card game and I want to have Room class (with unique room name, players at the moment online in room, socked id ...) so when some user join server to have fresh list of active rooms. And when one room is canceled (destroyed) I would send to all users that information (basically real-time Room(s) status).

---

Ok, here is reason why I want to do it. 
I am making card game project and I want to have Room class (with unique room name, players at the moment online in room, socked id ...) so when some user join server to have fresh list of active rooms. And when one room is canceled(destroyed) I would send to all users that information ( basically real-time Room(s) status ). I hope you understand what I want to do.

Comment: No, and unsure why you'd need to know... each server request isn't even aware of other server requests

Comment: This is seriously good and interesting question!

Comment: I am curious why you would want it, but it's highly interesting. I would use some nosql/memcache tracking for this task at starter.

Comment: @MarekSebera Sounds more like a xy problem to me tbh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to implement a multi-user game, so you should use a **client-server architecture** for it: Set up a single, persistent **server process** that runs on your machine and keeps track of game state. Each user request is handled by a PHP "client" script that talks to the game server and asks for all the necessary information.

That way, all the `Room` objects and all the player state live in a single process: The server. The webserver (not to be confused with your game server) launches the client threads, and they talk asynchronously to the game server in any way you want.

If your situation is really simple, you might be able to replace the server process with a centralized database that stores a snapshot of the current state of the game (including a full list of active rooms and the associated players). Each user request loads the game state from the database, and writes out any changes. But I think a long-running server is the easier way to go.

**Edit:** Your question suggests some confusion about how PHP works. PHP threads launched by the server to handle user requests are very short-lived. Let's say you have 5 players who've been at it for an hour. Every few minutes or seconds, a player sends a request to your webserver. The server launches a PHP thread that handles the request and exits. The game might last hours, but **most of the time there are *no* running threads and *no* instances of your class to count.** At all times, you'll have some players without active connections. So you need *some* sort of persistent entity to hold their game state between requests, and you might as well make it unique.

**Edit 2:** Since it seems you're a little over your head, maybe you should go with the second option: Forget about inter-process communication and keep the game state in a 
database:

Each php request is one player action. When the user clicks on a button or whatever, your php script loads from the database all the info it needs to model the current state of the game. It does any necessary house-cleaning (deactivate any users who stopped playing long ago), then handles the user's action, saves any changes to the database, and generates a fresh page for the user. Then it exits. It all takes a small fraction of a second. Then the next user (or the same user) submits another action, and you start again.

What about **concurrency?** Unless you manage to get a lot of users *and* your scripts are really slow, there won't be any: you will only ever run one copy of the script at a time. If you want to *prohibit* concurrent execution, use database transactions to ensure that user actions are processed one at a time. If that's still not enough, learn about client-server architectures, inter-process communication, and all the other stuff you need for the client-server solution.

Comment: Can you explain me server process a little bit or send some documentation(what is it?). I understand how it should work but still don't know how to make it.

Comment: The details depend on your OS. If you're on unix, your server can run as a "daemon". If on Windows, it's called a service. But any way to start a long-running process is fine. For more information, google "client-server architecture" and follow the links that seem relevant to what you're trying to do. To learn about the different ways your server can talk to the PHP client threads, google "inter-process communication".

Comment: I am over my head, but what is other way to learn? :) Tanks for answer I am on it now.

Comment: Good, have fun then. Don't bite off too much at once, IPC is messy.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely a crude approach, but you just put something in the constructor for the class.  That something could be to log something, email something, read a counter and increment etc...

Obviously if you wanted to know how many instances at any given point in time, you would need something in the destructor as well...

After reading your answer (which should have been a comment on your original question), the best way to implement this would be to use class methods and properties, that way any instance could read/alter the shared count.  You could still use the constructor and destructor to increment/decrement a count of active tables etc..., but the class would maintain a single count, accessible by all instances.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. The very long and convoluted answer is yes but it would require a ton of a hacking and either editing the php source or using gdb (or something of the like) to inspect the running memory. As far as I know there is absolutely no out of the box support for this.

The better question is WHY would you need this? You are most likely trying to solve a problem that is much easier to solve another way.

You may be able to get away with just using APC increment and decrement on object instantiation and destruction but if there are really so many of these objects that you need to count them then you could definitely cause a big performance issue.

Comment: No or yes? Difficult doesn't mean it isn't possible. The question is clear; asking "why" is not relevant (unconventional does not need to be discouraged). Performance implications and their importance are entirely unknown.

Comment: If the goal is to ultimately help someone and they are a software engineer you really need to consider what they are trying to solve. Many engineers will reduce a problem to what they think is the optimal subproblem (such as counting all instances of a variable on an entire server in php) when maybe they want to do something like keep track of how many SQL queries are ran (if say the object is a DTO).

Comment: That presupposes they are incapable of both assessing the problem and the proposed solutions. If you have already done the background work it is infuriating to continually hear "but why would you want to do that?" accompanied by no answer (that said, I appreciate that you did offer an answer). Is it worth that risk to elicit extra information from someone who maybe is misguided? I do not think so. People need to be dictated less dogma and subjected to more reality; allow them to solve the problem differently and reach their own conclusions on how difficult it is. Lives are not on the line.